# Adding a widget from activity to another activity's in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm developing a task reminder app and still not familiar with Android Studio. The layout was an Activity Form with a floating action button that opens the second activity for inputting name, date, time, etc., the second activity has a 'create' button that supposes to add a checkbox widget to the main activity form and I was having difficulties to make it work unlike at java where you just have to add it directly on its respective container.
By the way, this is how I created the object for my checkbox...

```
private class task extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox{
    task me;
    public task(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        me=this;
        me.setText(taskName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not correct to add a widget in another activity in real-time, there are many solutions for this case, the simplest way is to start the second activity with `startActivityForResult` and in the second activity,  return changes to the first activity and on `onActivityResult` handed if there are any changes or not, if yes create your widgets based on the returned result.

Comment: yo! thank you bro, I used the method you told and it really worked. Now I can move to the next thing to work with my app!